# Display <textarea> content in <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm really new to Javascript. I am trying to output the current date and also the content in the textarea tag in HTML on button click. 
However I do not know how to obtain the content when the textarea is not declared along with a name/id/class.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
   function displayPost() {
      var thisDiv = document.getElementById("posts");
      var date = new Date();
      date.classList.add("post-time");
      var textarea = document.getElementByTagName("textarea");
      textarea.classList.add("post-content");
      thisDiv.innerHTML = date + textarea;
   }
</script>


<html>
  <div id="posts"></div>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="60">Type your text here...</textarea>
  <button onclick = "displayPost()">Post</button>
</html>
```

Any sort of help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you don't want to add a class or id, you could query for the tag: [`document.querySelector('textarea')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get a reference to it. It'll return the first one it finds.

Comment: If you want to add a class or id in every situation, check your console and try to clear up console ... as I think there is error waiting for you on your console..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) when a dom element does have any name/id/class like:

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
```

To get the current date in a readable format, you can use [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) method:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
// → "3/21/2020, 7:00:00 PM"
```

To get `<textarea>` current entered value you can use:

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
console.log(textarea.value);
```

DEMO:

```js
function displayPost() {
  var thisDiv = document.getElementById('posts');
  var date = new Date();
  thisDiv.classList.add("post-time");
  var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
  textarea.classList.add("post-content");
  thisDiv.innerHTML = date.toLocaleString() + ': '+ textarea.value;
}
```

```css
.post-time{padding:20px 0}
```

```html
<div id="posts"></div>
<textarea rows="4" cols="60" placeholder="Type your text here..."></textarea>
<button onclick="displayPost()">Post</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  make use of `document.querySelector()` which returns first matching element or `document.getElementsByTagName()` which returns NodeList of all the textarea elements

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea').value;
```

or

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
```